# Apache 2 mpm-itk and mpm-prefork modules together

Tags: apache-2.4

Here is Apache 2 configuration:

*/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_itk.load*

```
# Depends: mpm_prefork
LoadModule mpm_itk_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mpm_itk.so
```

*/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.load*

```
# Conflicts: mpm_event mpm_worker mpm_itk
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

The comments don't add much clarity - mpm-prefork conflicts with mpm-itk, but mpm-itk depends on it?

When `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_itk.load` is removed, there is an error:

> AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.

I'm not sure what's going on there. Is mpm-itk broken or does it really depend on mpm-prefork?

Is it bad that both modules are loaded? Which of these modules is used by Apache in practice and why? How to make Apache use another one?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one MPM. So the comment doesn't make any sense. You might consider reporting the problem to the package maintainer.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to know which of MPM modules is in charge at this moment? `apache2ctl -M` shows both, and there are no errors on module conflict on Apache start. This is production server, so I would prefer to avoid trial and error if possible.

Comment: @michael-hamptonwhy I thought the same, but why on a working instance `sudo apache2ctl -M | grep mpm` return `mpm_itk_module` **and** `mpm_prefork_module`. BTW `sudo apachectl configtest` return _Syntax OK_.